# Дублируются посты в базе данных

Tags: php, javascript

После нажатия на submit происходит запись в бд,но если обновить страницу,то пост продублируется.Сначала делал скрипт с редиректом на эту же страницу и алертом,но срабатывал только алерт с сообщением,а редирект не происходил.Потом попробовал сделать редирект через onclick,но почему-то нужно было нажать второй раз,после того как данные записались,чтобы произошёл редирект.Искал решения,но они либо не работали либо были слишком сложные для моего понимания.Как решить?

Сабмит

```
<input type="submit" value="отправить"  onclick="window.open('news.php','_self');" />
```

php

```
<?php

            $title=$_POST['title'];
            $textarea=$_POST['textarea'];
            $img=$_POST['img'];

$db  =  new  PDO ('mysql:dbname=posting; host=localhost',"admin","1234");

$sql="insert into `news` (title,textarea,img) values (:title,:textarea,:img)";
$sth=$db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':title', $title);
$sth->bindValue(':textarea', $textarea);
$sth->bindValue(':img', $img);

$sth->execute();

    ?>
```

Comment: Ну добавьте проверку. Например, по идее не должно быть записей с одним и тем же заголовком - плохо для SEO. Добавьте в бд уникальный индекс по этому полю. При добавлении - проверяйте.

Comment: Почему-то не могу добавить автоинкремент к заголовку - не сохраняет.

Comment: Да,я так и не понял как добавить уникальный индекс,но сделал фильтрацию по заголовку и тексту,и теперь записи не дублируются!Спасибо.

Comment: не автоинкремент. А именно индекс. Чем вы пользуетесь для работы с БД?

Comment: Вопрос решён.Спасибо!